# Closure in JS for invoking CB once in a function. (Trying to solve an exercise.)

Tags: javascript, caching, callback, closures

Okay, so my question will be weirdly specific as I'm not just randomly learning JavaScript. I'm trying to follow along with a course, so I'm on the lesson about Closures, and I'm at an assignment where I need to finish this exercise. I've tried writing the code in several ways but I keep failing on the last bit of the instructions which specifies to only invoke once, like if the result is 25 and it's called again, it sees it was called by 5 once already, and just returns 25 still. But I'm stuck.

Here is the exercise:

```
 function cacheFunction(cb) {
      // use closure to create a cache for the cb function
      // the function that you return should accept a single argument and invoke cb with that argument
      // when the function you return is invoked with an argument it should save that argument and its result
      // when the function you return is called again with an argument that it has seen before it should not call cb
      // but should instead directly returned the previous result
      // example:
      // cb -> function(x) { return x * x; }
      // if the function you return is invoked with 5 it would pass 5 to cb(5) and return 25
      // if the function you return is invoked again with 5 it will look on an object in the closure scope
      // and return 25 directly and will not invoke cb again

    --Code here
 }
```

Now here is what I have and it's not working..

```
function cacheFunction(cb) {
    return function (number) {
      number + number;
      return cb(number);
    }
}
```

I know there is more to it and the way i wrote it, it isn't right, but I'm still new to this and any help would be appreciated. :)

Oh and my JS test for it says this:

> cacheFunction(cb)
>          √ should return the callback function (1ms)
>          √ should return the callback functions result when the cached function is invoked (1ms)
>          × should cache function results (4ms)

● cacheFunction(cb) › should cache function results

```
expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2)

Expected mock function to have been called two times, but it was called nine times.

  46 |              cachedFunction(10);
  47 |              cachedFunction(10);
> 48 |              expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  49 |      });
  50 | });
  51 |
```

Why was it called 9 times?

Comment: I'm not so clear of the exercise instruction. Can you explain it a bit clearer?

Answer (score 0):

By exercise requirements you need [memoization](http://www.algorithmist.com/index.php/Memoization). Simple definition in your case: don't call cb function if you already called cached function with the same number. I could give you an answer, but it will not help you learn the JS. So instead I will provide simple hints.

1. Your callback is calculator, so move `number + number` inside of it.
2. Second create store to hold your values. So if number was already sent, you do not need to recalculate. Think about variable type for store.
3. Think about first checking the store and if there is no value calculate and store the value.

About the why nine times, I hope you understand that if you cached function will be called nine times with the same arguments. It needs to call cb function only once

Comment: Oh, I think i understand. I have to read more then, as the basic instructions and the lesson they provide are kinda basic. I had to research more to solve a prior lesson, with how to use different techniques together, such as arrays and loops. This is lesson 10, surprised i got this far, really. Lots of trial and error. Okay so I'll post here if I get confused again, but I'll continue in the morning. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Concept used : Closures

Solution:
Instantiate only once using a boolean, which will be remembered because of closures in JS.

```
const numberFunc = ( num ) => num;


const RunOnlyOnce = ( fn ) => {

let value = null;

var isRun = false;

return function(...args){
    if(!isRun){
        isRun = true;
        value = fn(args);
    }
    return value;
  }
}

const callmeOnce = RunOnlyOnce(numberFunc);

callmeOnce(25); //25

callmeOnce(25); //25

callmeOnce(25); //25

callmeOnce(25); //25
```